# Paging with jquery - slice returns no results

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, slice

I'm trying to create my own paging plugin and I'm running into an issue: slice() returns zero results. Don't know why this is happening since the first set of results comes out fine. Could you guys help?

Here's the HTML:

```
<table class="pagination">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>First name</td>
            <td>Last name</td>
            <td>Age</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Mike</td>
            <td>Lee</td>
            <td>22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Matthew</td>
            <td>McGyver</td>
            <td>32</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Lucas</td>
            <td>Pereira</td>
            <td>17</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Miltiades</td>
            <td>Rochester</td>
            <td>52</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>Horace</td>
            <td>Evans</td>
            <td>64</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>Anthony</td>
            <td>Briggs</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>Raymond</td>
            <td>Mercer</td>
            <td>34</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>Richard</td>
            <td>Tex-Tex</td>
            <td>32</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>Ryu</td>
            <td>Hayabusa</td>
            <td>27</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>Zacariah</td>
            <td>Beckett</td>
            <td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>Jerome</td>
            <td>Coles</td>
            <td>29</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>43</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>Robert</td>
            <td>Pershing</td>
            <td>44</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the JavaScript (using jQuery 1.10.1):

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.pager = function (params) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            table: $(this).find("tbody"),
            pageSize: 5,
            currentPage: 0,
            totalPages: 0
        }, params);

        // Calculate total pages
        settings.totalPages = Math.round($(this).find("tbody tr").size() / settings.pageSize);

        var bar = $("<div></div>");
        var firstPage = $("<a href=\"#\">&lt;&lt;</a>");
        $(firstPage).on("click", function (event) {
            settings.currentPage = 0;
            drawWindow(settings);
            $(firstPage).attr('disabled', true);
            $(previousPage).attr('disabled', true);

            return false;
        });

        var previousPage = $("<a href=\"#\">&lt;</a>");
        $(previousPage).on("click", function (event) {
            if (settings.currentPage > 0) {
                settings.currentPage--;
            } else {
                $(firstPage).attr('disabled', true);
                $(previousPage).attr('disabled', true);
            }

            drawWindow(settings);

            return false;
        });

        var nextPage = $("<a href=\"#\">&gt;</a>");
        $(nextPage).on("click", function (event) {
            if (settings.currentPage < (settings.totalPages - 1)) {
                settings.currentPage++;
            } else {
                $(firstPage).attr('disabled', false);
                $(previousPage).attr('disabled', false);
                $(nextPage).attr('disabled', true);
                $(lastPage).attr('disabled', true);
            }

            drawWindow(settings);

            return false;
        });

        var lastPage = $("<a href=\"#\">&gt;&gt;</a>");
        $(lastPage).on("click", function (event) {
            settings.currentPage = settings.totalPages - 1;

            $(firstPage).attr('disabled', false);
            $(previousPage).attr('disabled', false);
            $(nextPage).attr('disabled', true);
            $(lastPage).attr('disabled', true);

            drawWindow(settings);

            return false;
        });

        $(bar).append(firstPage);
        $(bar).append(previousPage);
        $(bar).append(nextPage);
        $(bar).append(lastPage);
        $(this).append(bar);

        drawWindow(settings);
        $(firstPage).attr('disabled', true);
        $(previousPage).attr('disabled', true);
    };

    function drawWindow(settings) {
        var window = settings.pageSize;
        var start = settings.currentPage * window;

        alert("Start " + start);
        // To do: Why zero when start is 5 and window is 5?
        alert("Records " + settings.table.find("tr").slice(start, window).size());
        // Show only required results
        $(settings.table.find("tr")).not($(settings.table.find("tr")).slice(start, window)).hide();
    }
}(jQuery));

$(".pagination").pager();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a couple of things.

First I think your calculations for setting `settings.currentPage` are wrong. Initially the `currentPage` is `0`. If you click *once* on the arrows to move through the dataset the `currentPage` is `2`, not `1` which it should be.

Second, this is what your code is trying to do on the 'second' page.

```
settings.table.find("tr").slice(10, 5)
```

This will return nothing because you're trying to start at 10 and work back to 5, and slice doesn't work like that. So work out what variables you need to change to get this to work.

Finally, assigning variables to `window`, even if it's a local variable, is precarious at best and you need to get out of the habit of doing so.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Andy, Where do you see that the second page is slice(10, 5)? It is slice(5, 5). I see what you are trying to say by working back, it helped notice my error - I was under the impression it was slice([starting item], [number of items to obtain]) instead of slice([starting item], [end item]). Thank you for so gently mentioning that my variable was conflicting with "window". I've changed it.

Comment: Add an alert/console.log to `drawWindow()`: `console.log(start, window);` You will see that the variables on the second page are 10 (for `start`) and 5 (for `window`), the variables you try to use in the slice.